how to add left green border with curved top and bottom?

As shown in the image  how to add left side green border?
I want to add this type of border to UIview. I have tried to put this type of image inside view but that is not working in my case because it can't manage with dynamic height of the cell.
so please give me a proper solution to add layer to a view.
Edit:
private func addBorderImage() {
    print("commit init")
    guard let img = UIImage(named: "BorderLeft") else {
        fatalError("Could not load image named \"stretch1\"!!!")
    }
    // create a resizable version
    let stretchImg = img.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .init(top: 12.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 12.0, right: 0.0))
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    imgView.image = stretchImg.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imgView.tintColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")
    
    imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(imgView)
    
    let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
        imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: -10.0),
        imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25.0),
    ])
    
}

and I am using png image but resizing is not working.

You can do this with a resizableImage.
We'll start with this image (clipped from your posted image):

It is 11 x 32 (pixels).
We can make it "stretchable" using func resizableImage(withCapInsets capInsets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage (docs) like this:
.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .init(top: 12.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 12.0, right: 0.0))

Now the top 12-pixels and bottom 12-pixels will not stretch ... only the middle part will:

Sample code:
class StretchTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "stretch1") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!!!")
        }
        
        // create a resizable version
        let stretchImg = img.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .init(top: 12.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 12.0, right: 0.0))
        
        // now let's add 8 image views with increasing heights
        var x: CGFloat = 40.0
        var h: CGFloat = 60.0
        
        for _ in 1...8 {
            let imgView = UIImageView()
            imgView.image = stretchImg
            imgView.frame = .init(x: x, y: 100.0, width: 11.0, height: h)
            view.addSubview(imgView)
            
            x += 30.0
            h += 50.0
        }
    }
    
}


Edit - really quick example with variable height table view cells...
class StretchCellViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    let rowsInCell: [Int] = [
        2, 3, 7, 5, 2, 4, 8, 5, 9, 6,
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        tableView.register(StretchImageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: StretchImageCell.identifier)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowsInCell.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StretchImageCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! StretchImageCell
        c.fillData(numRows: rowsInCell[indexPath.row])
        return c
    }
}

class StretchImageCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier: String = "StretchImageCell"
    
    private let stack = UIStackView()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "stretch1") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image named \"stretch1\"!!!")
        }
        // create a resizable version
        let stretchImg = img.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .init(top: 12.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 12.0, right: 0.0))
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        imgView.image = stretchImg

        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 8
        
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(imgView)
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(stack)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 11.0),

            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.trailingAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        for _ in 1...10 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: .light)
            v.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
    }

    public func fillData(numRows: Int) {
        // hide all the labels in the stack view
        for v in stack.arrangedSubviews {
            v.isHidden = true
        }
        // limit to 10 label rows
        let n = min(10, numRows)
        // now set label text and un-hide
        for i in 0..<numRows {
            if let v = stack.arrangedSubviews[i] as? UILabel {
                v.text = "Label number: \(i+1)"
                v.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
}

Result:


Thank you for answering but can you please draw it in layer because i am facing height issue in table view cell.  And it is not possible to use image in my case.

@AshaGohel - I don't understand what you mean by "it is not possible to use image in my case".

I mean I am using dynamic height in the table view cell And I want this border in the entire cell. so the image is not taking proper height and my cell's content is being misplaced.

@AshaGohel - the example shows how the image stretches to fill the height of the image view, while keeping the top and bottom ends static. Give it a try. Add an image view to your cell ... constrain it so its height expands when the cell is taller. That's the whole point of resizableImage(withCapInsets:...)

@AshaGohel - I added a quick, simple example of using resizableImage(withCapInsets:...) in a table view cell.

I have edited the question please check again.

@AshaGohel - you need to provide more detail than "I am using png image but resizing is not working" ... What didn't work? Looking at the code you added, is your "BorderLeft" image 15-pixels wide? Are you using @2x and @3x images? Post the actual .png file(s) you are trying to use, and post an image of the result.

I was using an SVG image so resizing was not working properly, now it's working with a PNG image thank you for your guidance.
